# Use AVCaptureSession in Swift without using Built-in Camera

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession

I am streaming an IPCamera into my App using VLC library and have access to the stream as either a `UIImage`, or a `UIView`.

I want to utilize the `AVCaptureSession` functionality that is typically used with either the front or rear camera, but instead shove my video feed into the preview layer. I can't find anything that seems to have an example of this, if anyone has any insight it would be most appreciated.